# Assume Role : Unable to load credentials from system settings

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Created a Java application and deployed in an EC2 instance, associated the EC2 Instance profile role to the Instance

While making calls to the AWS APIs through AWS Java SDK V2 as well as V1 getting the below error

```
KmsClient client = KmsClient.builder().region(amazonSessionMapper.getRegion()).build();
```

Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).

Is there anything related to the permission/settings

Note: I don't want to use Access Key and Secret Key with the application, I wanted to assume role using the STS

```
FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37|software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: 
Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
 or system property (aws.accessKeyId). FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37|   
 at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:98) ~[software.amazon.awssdk-sdk-core-2.16.84.jar:?] 
 FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37| at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.internal.SystemSettingsCredentialsProvider.
 resolveCredentials(SystemSettingsCredentialsProvider.java:58) ~[software.amazon.awssdk-auth-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37|  
 at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProviderChain.resolveCredentials(AwsCredentialsProviderChain.java:91) 
 ~[software.amazon.awssdk-auth-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37|    
 at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.internal.LazyAwsCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials(LazyAwsCredentialsProvider.java:45) 
 ~[software.amazon.awssdk-auth-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37|    
 at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.DefaultCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:104) 
 ~[software.amazon.awssdk-auth-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37|    
 at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsClientHandlerUtils.createExecutionContext(AwsClientHandlerUtils.java:79) 
 ~[software.amazon.awssdk-aws-core-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37|    
 at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.createExecutionContext(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:68) 
 ~[software.amazon.awssdk-aws-core-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37|    
 at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:99) 
 ~[software.amazon.awssdk-sdk-core-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37|    
 at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:169) 
 [software.amazon.awssdk-sdk-core-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37| 
 at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:95) 
 [software.amazon.awssdk-sdk-core-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37| 
 at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45) 
 [software.amazon.awssdk-sdk-core-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37| 
 at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55) 
 [software.amazon.awssdk-aws-core-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37| 
 at software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.DefaultKmsClient.listAliases(DefaultKmsClient.java:4466) 
 [software.amazon.awssdk-kms-2.16.84.jar:?] FINEST|1432182/0|Service controller|22-01-20 13:49:37|  
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.KmsClient.listAliases(KmsClient.java:7885) [software.amazon.awssdk-kms-2.16.84.jar:?]ases(KmsClient.java:7885) [software.amazon.awssdk-kms-2.16.84.jar:?]
```

Comment: How are you using the credentials? Can you share this part of our code?

Comment: KmsClient client = KmsClient.builder().region(US_EAST_1).build();

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a credentialsProvider and use in your client:

```
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
```

Then you will be able to use this provider with the `.withCredentials` method:

```
 AWSKMS kmsClient = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .withRegion("us-east-1")
                .build();
```